# Combinatorics, find all 10 length arrays of positive integers whose sum is equal to 100

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

At the beginning, I was trying to solve (apparently) another problem but it led me to this one.

```
"Find all 10 length arrays of non-negative integers whose sum is equal to 100."
```

Here are some examples:

10 - 35 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 55 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0

1  - 2 - 3 - 96 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0

12 - 0 - 12 - 26 - 0 - 1 - 1 - 38 - 10 - 0

...

Firstly, I tried to write a little program but it takes hours (it is 10 for-loop in a word). So I asked myself, if there were a better algorithm or even better a mathematical formula to do so?

Good luck and thank you.

PS: Of course, you can make the problem more general by changing "10" and "100" to "k" and "n" variables.

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: This can also be done with generating function.

Comment: First comment works perfectly, thank you. @Kaladin, can you tell me more about your solution?

Comment: Zero is not a positive integer.  Perhaps you meant non-negative integers or natural numbers?

Comment: You're right. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

All the part of the arrays have as generating function $1+x+x^2+x^3+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$. So the total generating function is $(\frac{1}{1-x})^{k+1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$. Then notice $k$-th derivative of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ equals $k!\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}
$. Therefor $\frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^\text{k-th derivative}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$ 
On the other hand the $k$-th derivative is also $k!+(k+1)!x+\frac{(k+2)!}{2!}x^2+...+\frac{(k+n)!}{n!}x^n+....$ So we get that $\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{n+k\choose k}x^n$. We can see the coefficient in front of $x^{n}$ is ${n+k\choose k}$